# Qt Creator - Code is running but I get an error message from the IDE

Tags: c++, c, qt, ide, qt-creator

As soon as I run my code (note that I'm using C only, no QT and no C++) I get the following message from the application output inside the IDE:

> Cannot obtain a handle to the inferior: The parameter is incorrect.

When I delete the makefiles and debug/release folders it's running but after some time I still get the error. It's not that much of a problem though, the code runs and everything is fine but this error pops up and it's quite annoying.

The content of the .pro file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
QMAKE_CC = gcc -std=c99
SOURCES += main.c
```

Thanks in advance!

---

edit: I have added C++ tag, because this error occurs also for C++ console application as in my case.

Comment: do you have multiple versions of qt installed?  Have you edited your path variable lately? http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21311

Comment: No, just this one. Also I noticed I'm getting errors with the MSVC compilers when I go to Options>Build&Run>QT Versions

Answer (score 8):

I have met same problem. Tips and advices on forums are rather clueless, so I investigated problem myself and I have found that it's a bug in QtCreator.

There is dirty little program called `qtcreator_process_stub`. Whenever you run your program within IDE, IDE first runs `qtcreator_process_stub` and passes your program name as parameter (among some other parameters). `qtcreator_process_stub` then starts your program as separate process and prints its PID (and on windows also thread id). Information is printed to the pipe and then it is read by [`ConsoleProcess::readStubOutput()`](https://github.com/danimo/qt-creator/blob/master/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_win.cpp#L215), which is part of `Utils.dll` library used by QtCreator.

The problem occurs when "inferior" process (your application) finishes execution before whole communication has been processed. [`ConsoleProcess::readStubOutput()`](https://github.com/danimo/qt-creator/blob/master/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_win.cpp#L215) attempts to use [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on non-existing process with closed handle. [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails hence error "Cannot obtain a handle to the inferior: The parameter is incorrect.". Whole error is not handled very gently (*Uhm, and now what?*)... :-/

**Solution:**
When you add some user input action, pause, sleep, delay or just some loops, so that execution of your application is a bit longer error vanishes. There is enough time for [`ConsoleProcess::readStubOutput()`](https://github.com/danimo/qt-creator/blob/master/src/libs/utils/consoleprocess_win.cpp#L215) to execute `OpenProcess()`, before your application quits. So as a workaroud I suggest to do that until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly right (and the other discussions of it are in the dark).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It seems that you are right about this. Adding e.g. a `system("pause");` statement does tend to this error, as you predicted. See the [corresponding QtBug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13042); this particular error only occurs on Windows btw.

Comment: @doc, I've done you suggestion and it worked. I removed  `system("pause");` and run the app again, the error didn't show up again. I don't know why but this what happens.

Comment: @CroCo it may show up again. Follow link posted by Joost. Download process_stub.zip from attachments, compile it and replace original qtcreator_process_stub.exe (just rename original one to keep undo option).

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error repeatedly while working on a C++ project in Qt. I was able to solve it by copying one of the shared libraries(.dll) I was using in to the build folder.

So, if you are using any shared external libraries that are needed at runtime, make sure they are in the builds folder.